# Best practice with memcache expiration in PHP

Tags: php, mysql, caching, memcached

I use Memcache servers for caching my website. 
So, I don't know which is the best pratices between caching with UNLIMITED time and update cached objects when I update Mysql. Or if it's better to cache object during a small period (depends on usage ;) )

Example :

- List of blog posts (update every hour) : expiration time 1h VS unlimited expiration time and update when article are submitted
- A blog post ( update ... never ? ) : unlimited expiration time is better than an expiration time of 1 day

Can you explain your methods and your pratices ?

Answer (score 0):

If there are going to be no changes to the blog post I would just leave it in memory and wait for an eviction for it to re-set.